# Control whether or not to trash a custom post type

Tags: trash

I need to have control over the trash / delete action on a custom post type.

I need to check for some conditions and decide if i should trash the CPT or not.

The wp_trash_action hook that is fired before the trash function does not give me the option to cancel the trash procedure.

To be more specific , i need to check for a condition when the user presses TRASH. If that condition is false then i need to stop the trashing action. If it is true it should continue.

Comment: *does not give me this option*, what option? Your question is very generic. Please file an [edit] and explain what you exactly need to do in order to get a specific to-the-point answer.

Comment: @PieterGoosen just did.

Comment: Use plugin [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/trash-manager/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook onto `trashed_post` and use `wp_untrash_post()` to reverse upon meeting a condition, pseudocode example...

```
add_action('trashed_post', 'wpse_218031_trashed_post');

function wpse_218031_trashed_post($post_id){
   //use post_id to check conditions... if not met call:
   if ( $some_condition ) {
       wp_untrash_post($post_id);
   }
}
```

`trashed_post` runs after `wp_trash_post` and after the post is moved to trash.

By the way, if the constant `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS` is defined and is `false` posts will be permanently deleted and the subsequent hooks mentioned will not be fired, in which case `wp_delete_post()` will be called instead.